# Why are comments allowed to be modified/deleted?

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

This is more of an opinion/request than a question.

In my experience comments are widely used to clarify/debate the question, and certainly are useful, for that matter they shouldn't be treated as second class citizens.

I understand that obscene and / or otherwise impermissible comments should be censored out and rendered invisible for the public, I'm only speaking here for the "decent" and permissible ones here.

I consider considerably harmful for the clarity and integrity of the comments for a given question, that they can be edited/deleted by the user at a later time.

People are responding to each others previous comments. This rather takes form of a conversation between commenters as a succession of questions, answers, referrals to previous comments, each comment being relevant and meaningful only in the context of all previous comments *as they were* at the time of the comment being posted. If comments are allowed to be modified or to be deleted, this invalidates all comments that answer or reflect on the given comment, making them nonsensical for the reader. This compromises the comments section as a whole, rendering it useless, nevertheless it condones unethical user behavior (on a more subtle level), as encourages users to not take responsibility for their comments, hence they can be deleted/edited ulteriorly without a trace.

It would be nice, that user comment edits/deletes merely apply a "strike-through" to the original text to signal that the user corrected it, and for the sake of brevity or for the sake of not cluttering the interface too much with deleted/edited parts we could have a filter that shows/hides these strike-through texts (but it should be clear at all times, that a comment is no longer identical to the original, and a comment once posted should be readable at any given time even if it was deleted [by the user]).

I also understand that the site is about getting precise answers to questions, and not about chatting, but lets not forget that comments are the way of communication between people who ask the questions and people who answer them, so it should be important to keep it sane.

Comment: "*user comment edits/deletes merely apply a "strike-through" to the original text*" seems like it would make things much harder to read, and isn't really a standard anywhere else. I don't really agree that is a good idea.

Comment: After the first few minutes a comment is posted, it's not editable by normal users.

Comment: "*I consider considerably harmful for the clarity and integrity of the comments for a given question, that they can be edited/deleted by the user at a later time.*" Just to make sure: you understand that this later time is a five minutes period, after which comments cannot be edited yes? In other words, in five minutes from now I will be unable to edit this comment, while retaining the ability to delete it.

Answer (score 12):

This is a big yikes for me.

Comments are only really meant to ask clarifying questions on someone's question so that the answer can be that much more valuable.  Any *other* use of comments dilutes their purpose and place on the site.

You can't search them; they're not indexed by any web crawler.  They should remain second-class citizens on the site.

Answer (score 8):

This site's raison d'etre is not to permit users to have a conversation, it's to permit questions to be answered. Comments are always going to be secondary to that and once there is a good answer or set of good answers ought to be mostly obsolete and therefore removable.

Having comments left with strike through would simply clutter up space. My original comment on this question for instance has no value now that I've incorporated its text into my answer. I've deleted it so nobody needs to waste time reading what I've written here twice.

If you find a set of comments that no longer make sense because some have been deleted, feel free to flag them so they can be deleted too.

Comment: May I be alone, on the subject of comments being important, but still: in the mean time a question get answered, all who read it, _will_ read through the comments. Although their life-span may be short, but while they are "alive", they should be useful. And indeed they can degenerate in the process of editing / deleting.

Comment: Yes, we will read the comments, so we better make sure they really *are* important. Any clarification should be integrated into the post. Any question about details should result in an action in the post.

Comment: To make my point more clear: if I'm seeking an answer, and I find the question already asked, but not yet answered, yet I see bunch of comments that half of them I don't understand because they are referring to deleted,/edited comments, then they loose their value altoghether. Plus I get a sense of "hey these people who wrote these comments are not makeing sense at all" while this is not true at all.

Comment: I think I understand @ÁronVárhelyi. In practice, I think we are trying to express to you that it really does not happen that much and that you can flag leftover comments. If you have concrete examples, maybe you can edit links towards those examples in your question?

Comment: Well I cant pinpoint examples, because the matter is somewhat summation of my experience, and unfortunately I get this a lot. The solution seems not to be to "flag the rest of the comments" and delete it. Than you take the effort of the people making the comments in vain. Than again, relevant comments are not deleted, but nonetheless they remain obscure if they add on a previous comment (as I said comments are interrelated, as one does not repeat what already has been said)

Comment: Are these comments vital to my answer? Can you understand the answer without them? Do you need to edit your question instead as suggested by Félix?

Comment: Well, if debating and clarifying the question is vital to understanding and answering it, than definitely yes. After all, if only the question and the answer matter, and the people producing the answer and their comfort or at least making their job a little easier, yet the clients reading the question does not matter, than the whole  thing somewhat shoots himself in the foot...

Comment: @ÁronVárhelyi Debating and clarifying the question could indeed be vital to understand it, but the results of that debate should be incorporated into the question and the comments be cleaned up. Nobody should have to sift through comments to grasp the topic.

Comment: Agreed, than its only matter of presentation if you present the answers before the comments all solved. The matter is rather of "user experience" as for the user that answers questions as well as for whom make the questions. After all, we are only humans...

Comment: To cut the long story short, not only the end result are important, but the process off getting there, and the involved peoples experience are also important. In my humble opinion. (another 2c :))

Comment: @Robert Longson: Good thing you edited your post. You see, before this topic gets closed, in that period of time all who read this, are reading the comments. Till the end product: the answer(s) are ready and set, this dispute between us is read by people who are potentially answering the question. Someone reading through our comments may be inspired to come up with a different, useful answer, specially for questions that are not all black and white. For people pondering the question, alteration of debate history is fallacy that wastes everybodies time.

Comment: @ÁronVárhelyi "_For people pondering the question, alteration of debate history is fallacy that wastes everybodies time._" - And none of this debate history can be altered because all of it is older than 5 minutes. So - I still don't see your point.

Comment: idk, those 5 minutes seems to be enough for users to mess up consistency. Its kind of strange (maybe its just me), one would assume that a string of comments are linear and unbroken chain and represent true order of conversation and thoughts.

Comment: @ÁronVárhelyi Maybe it's not you indeed, I, for one, have totally non-linear train of thoughts, can go on multiple ideas branching from a single one and can entertain multiple ideas at once. I am totally not in agreement with your opinion that there should be a single linear follow-through in the comments, nor that it is any valid representation of "thoughts".